# Comparison of machine learning algorithms and neural networks in python (Target leakage)

Tags: keras, scikit-learn, time-series, recurrent-neural-network

I am currently working on a project where i want to predict energy demands of heat pumps from households (Regression problem). The data is a timeseries with 365 timesteps.

I created several features to improve the performance of the model, for example:

- decomposition (trend, residual, seasonal)
- statistical features (e.g. mean value over the last 7 days)

Thus, when using "normal" machine learning algorithms, like a SVR or random forest, i have to shift these features otherwise this would be target leakage. For example: to calculate the trend for this particular day, i would need the energy demand for this day.

Now, i tried a recurrent neural network. For data preprocessing i normalized my data and created a dataset with sliding windows using keras's `tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array()`. I used the following parameters:

```
sampling_rate = 1
sequence_length = 3
delay = 0
batch_size = 32

num_train_samples = int(0.8 * len(X_red))
num_val_samples = int(0.1 * len(X_red))
num_test_samples = len(X) - num_train_samples - num_val_samples
```

The training data now results in the following shape:
The 0-2 timesteps are taken to predict the 3th value of the target.
In the next timestep, the features of the 1-3 timesteps are taken to predict the 4th value of the target and so on.

I already tried to manipulate the input data for the neural network so that there is definitely target leakage (0-2 timesteps as input to predict the 2th value of target) and the mean absolute error improved from 20 to 5 which is a great improvement for my data. This is confusing, because from the metric (MAE of 20) it seems that there is no data leakage, since there was such a great improvement after leaking on purpose.

Now my questions:

1. When using rolling windows and a neural network, do i still have to shift my input variables? I use the input variables of the last 3 days to predict the value of the 4th day, but i dont include any features of the 4th day, right? I am really confused about this. Using this kind of input structure of data, i thought there is no target leakage. If not, can someone explain me why this would be target leakage.
2. If my assumption in 1 is correct, how can i compare neural network models with machine learning models. The datasets are different then.

Comment: Your premises are correct. You shouldn't include features from the Nth day in your prediction as in the real world; you won't have those. I don't see a reason to think you have target leakage. Can you elaborate on why you are hypothesizing that?

Comment: @VictorMaricato I'm just not sure if this is target leakage, because if I use the data for normal machine learning models, then this is definitely target leakage. 

My problem is that I have two different data sets: For normal machine learning models I shift my features by one time step. For neural networks this is apparently not necessary, because I use rolling windows and thus do not shift the features by one time step.

If I compare these models for e.g. with MAE, is this valid ? I am now using two different data sets.

Comment: Yes, you can compare 2 different feature processing and model strategies. The core is: your test set has to be the same to evaluate these two strategies, and your conclusion won't be: Model A is better than Model B. It'll be: Model A with Feature Processing A is better than Model B with Feature Processing B.